# Parse JWT token payload data to get certain value in android/java

Tags: java, android, jwt

I just got introduced to the JWT and wanted to know how to parse the payload data to get a certain value from it using the key.

Example in the following JWT token          eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.TJVA95OrM7E2cBab30RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ

The payload data contains the following object when decoded in jwt.io

```
{
    "sub" : "1234567890"
    "name" : "John Doe"
    "admin" : "true"
}
```

I want to be able to parse this object to get the value of name which in this case is John Doe from the above JWT token.

I have already read this [Android JWT parsing payload/claims when signed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34998859/android-jwt-parsing-payload-claims-when-signed)

But i wanted to know if there is efficient way to do this in android using some library. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it, by normally parsing the string and decoding it from base64 and then casting the string to JSONObject and parsing the JSONObject to get the required value.

Comment: can you please post an example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56399692/java-8-base64-jwt-token-into-json

Comment: `String payload = new String(Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(jwt.split("\\.")[1]))`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Java JWT](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt) for that:

```
String name = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(keyUsedWhenSigningJwt).parseClaimsJws("base64EncodedJwtHere").getBody().get("name", String.class);
```